# KineticJS - Mouse cursor doesn't change over image

Tags: kineticjs

I use this to get a pointing hand when the mouse hovers over an image object:

```
imageObject.on('mouseover', function () {
  document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
```

This works great on one PC, but does not on other two PCs. All are Linux Debian (Jessie) with firefox 30.0. I don't get any error message on the console.

Interestingly, with the Chrome browser, this works on all three PCs.

How can this be? I am clueless.

Comment: Not sure why that is happening, but can't you use regular CSS? `img:hover { cursor: pointer; }`?

Comment: Don't know how to do that from within javascript. The image object is declared though kineticjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit! It was noScript! As soon as I deactivated it, the mouse cursor changes again when hovering over the object as wanted.

So one solution is to disable noScript completely. But I tried to find a setting in the options of noScript that could solve the problem, and I found it. Just uncheck BOTH settings under Advanced > ClearClick (untrusted AND trusted). That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
imageObject.on('mouseover', function () {
  $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it out, but it is not working at all, not even with chrome. Do I have to change 'body' somehow?

Comment: You can try `jQuery('body')` instead of `$('body')`.

Comment: Yes, now it works with chrome again, but firefox still not working. I cannot understand why the behaviour is different on different PCs. Any firefox setting I am not aware of?